# Issues with JDK 1.8 and java.xml.transform.Transformer

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, saxon

I'm using java.xml.transform.Transformer to add authentication header to a SOAP request. My application is running on JDK1.8.

When the line of code below is executed I get the subsequent warning message logged to the console

Code snippet:

```
transformer.transform(authenticationHeader, header.getResult());
```

Logged warning:

```
XML Parser does not recognize the feature http://xml.org/sax/features/validation
```

The output is a warning and does not prevent the request completing successfully however i would like to remove from log files.

I'm using Maven and do not explicitly specify Xerces or Saxon, Xalan etc. My application is using code which was generated using the Maven cxf-codegen-plugin

When I debug this issue i can see that the warning is generated in net.sf.saxon.event.Sender

Can anyone either;

1. A solution whereby my code uses a valid feature name or
2. A means to suppress the warning message from my log output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to attack this one from both ends: (a) why is the validation feature being requested, and (b) why is the parser not recognizing it.

(a) Why is it being requested? Saxon will request this feature if the application requests DTD-based validation, for example by doing Configuration.setValidation(true). There are probably various other places this request can be made.

(b) Why is it not recognized? The name http://xml.org/sax/features/validation is documented as a feature of Apache Xerces, but I've no idea if the built-in JDK parser supports it or not: it's not easy to find that documentation. In the XMLReader javadoc, it's not described as a feature that every parser must recognize, but it is used as an example feature name. I always have my environment configured to use Apache Xerces by default, so it require some effort to run tests to see what features are supported if Apache Xerces isn't present.

Perhaps the parser isn't actually the JDK default but some other parser - perhaps a user-written filter that isn't the "real" parser, but filters the output from the real parser (this is quite common, and it's a common mistake for such filters not to pass on configuration settings to the underlying parser). Unfortunately there are some paths where Saxon reports which parser has rejected the request, but that's not the case for this particular path. I'll fix that.

It's not as simple as ignoring the warning. If the application is requesting DTD validation and it isn't happening, that could have serious consequences. Children could die.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. But I suggested various possibilities, and I would love to know (as would others coming here later) what the final answer actually was.